# Angular: How to prevent direct access to lazy child module route via browser

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-router

I am developing a multi-module application using Angular 9. Here is my main application routing module.

Here is **AppRoutingModule** and it loads lazy **DemoModule**.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [SecGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'demo',
        loadChildren: () => import('demo').then((m) => m.DemoModule),
       },
      { path: 'not-found-page', component: NotFound404PageComponent, canActivate: [SecGuard] },
    ],
  },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found-page' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is the code of **DemoRoutingModule**

```
export const CTS_ROUTES: Routes = [{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [SecGuard] }];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CTS_ROUTES)],
   exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DemoRoutingModule {}
```

Here is my AppModule

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
      CommonModule,
     CoreModule.forRoot(configuration),
     DemoModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
      ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   })
  export class AppModule {}
```

Now when I access  `http://localhost:4200/demo/dashboard` everything is normal.

[image]

But when I try to access `http://localhost:4200/dashboard`  which I don't want to do. Then the result is like below image.

[image]

I want to access child components (which in this case *DashboardComponent*) only via the parent path */demo/dashboard*.

How can I achieve this functionality? Any idea?

Comment: Can you add your AppModule or check if u are importing demomodule in the AppModule?

Comment: @GowthamRajJ I had imported DemoModule inside AppModule

Comment: Could you remove it and try? Angular resolves lazy loaded modules from routing module.

Comment: @GowthamRajJ you are rigth. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GowthamRajJ had commented, Angular resolves lazy loaded modules from the routing module. No Need to import lazy-loaded module inside your AppModule.

Answer (score 2):

In your guard, you could create a state (boolean fromParent).

When you access your parent component (demo/dashboard), you set it to true.
Then, when you try to access your child component, you check fromParent, if it is true, then you're good to go, if not, you redirect to another page.
Don't forget to reset fromParent once you are your child component.